# Error Message when logging into WordPress on Xampp

Tags: multisite, login, localhost, cms, xampp

I have two Wordpress sites running on Xampp.  I am getting an error when logging into the second site I set up, it say's 'username is not registered on this site.  If you are unsure of your username, try your email address instead.'  I can only login to the first site I created.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you use exactly the same details when you created the admin account on both installs? It's one of like two screens during the install process. You could copy the db data from one install the other, but if it's a fresh local install with nothing important on, you could just reinstall the secondary and make sure to check the remember option this time when you setup the admin account.

Answer (score 0):

Does the 'bad' site public-facing page display? If not, then you have database issues (doesn't exist, permissions, user account, etc). Check the wp-config.php file to make sure that the database name/user/password is correct.

If the public-facing page displays, then use phpMyAdmin (or similar) tool to look at the wp-users table in the database specified by the site's wp-config.file. Make sure the name/email is correct and the same as what you are trying to use.  There are many googles/bings/ducks on how to change the password directly in the database.

Also, look at the error.log file for the 'bad' site to see if there are hints there as to the issue.